# REST uri naming conventions for junction tables

Tags: node.js, rest, express, sails.js

Let's say I've three tables

```
product (id, name)
customer (id, name)
product_customer (product_id, customer_id)
```

I've following REST services (URI'S) already in place for the `product` and `customer`

```
GET /products => get all products 
GET /products/:id => get details on a specific product
POST /products => add a product
PUT /products/:id => update a product
DELETE /products/:id => delete a product

Same as above for /customers
```

**Question**

Now join table `product_customer` needs a URI AND REST convention to retrieve records as per following needs

a) `/product_customer`  (will pass `customer_id` param to get all products bought by the customer)

b) `/product_customer` (will pass `product_id` param to get all customers who bought this product)

I need a REST uri convention for join tables to be able to retrieve records by both params, is there any standard convention out there?

**Edit Sample JSON**

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "product 1"
    }
  ],
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "john"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "jane"
    },        
  ]
}
```

**Edit 2 - Suggested URI's based on the comments**

**Plural (with s)**

`GET /products` - List all products

`GET /products/1` - Detail like name etc. for the product id 1 (no customers)

**Singular**

`GET /product/1` - Detail of a product plus it's customers

`GET /product/1/customers`  Only customers of product 1

Comment: Singular or plural forms depends on the name of Model. If model name is *product*, then request is `GET /product/1` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you created [Many-to-many](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations/ManytoMany.html) associations in you models like:

*api/models/Product.js*

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true
        },
        name:'string',

        // Add a reference to Customer model
        customers: {
            collection: 'customer',
            via: 'products'
        }
    }
}
```

*api/models/Customer.js*

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'integer',
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            unique: true
        },
        name:'string',

        // Add a reference to Product model
        products: {
            collection: 'product',
            via: 'customers'
        }
    }
}
```

After that you will be able to request through [Blueprint API](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/Populate.html):

All **customers** for **product** ID 1:

```
GET /product/1/customers
```

All **products** for **customer** ID 5:

```
GET /customer/5/products
```

**Please note, that model name is product and customer are singular - without 's', and their associations are products and customers! This how I like, you can name like you want.**

Comment: nice, I'm not using Sails.js but would like to use it's conventions in my custom app, so `GET /product/1/customers` means get "details" about product id 1 and a list of all it's customers? not just customers, detail of the product as well. please confirm

Comment: can you please help with my JSON output as well, my format is `{ "product": [  {"id": 1, "name": "prod1"} ], "customers": [ {"id": 1, "name": "john"}, {"id": 2, "name": "Doe"} ]]` products and customers are at the same level or am I required to nest the customers inside products? Editing my question for visibility

Comment: It will return you back ALL of the related customers to that product with all their fileds. If you want to get product and customers in one request, then just `GET /product/1`

Comment: I've actually `GET /product/1` for product details only (without customers) and I've another requirement to return the detail of the product detail + customers. I wanna enforce standards, is there a solution or should I ask them to make two calls instead?

Comment: What is that JSON for? If your question is that is what SAILS returns - the answr is now. The correct returned data will be something like: `{
  "customers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "John",
      "createdAt": "2015-05-28T09:50:51.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2015-05-28T09:50:51.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Doe",
      "createdAt": "2015-05-29T09:57:51.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2015-05-29T09:57:51.000Z"
    }
  ],
  "id": 1,
  "name": "prod1",
  "createdAt": "2015-05-15T10:03:01.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2015-05-26T07:17:14.000Z"
}`

Comment: thanks for the JSON sample, so my other comment, what routes should I set for the following, - 1) Get Product Detail - 2) Get product detail + customers. or should I tell them, for request #2, they need to make two calls, one for `GET /product/1` and second `GET /product/1/customers`, or is there a way to combine the two. please confirm.

Comment: `GET /product/1` will output product and ALL associations made in model.

Comment: `GET /product/1/customers` will output only customers for product with ID 1

Comment: well sorry Bulkin, I actually tagged sails.js to pull people with knowledge, otherwise it's a non-sails.js, totally custom, I'm learning standards out there from frameworks, and I understand from your last comments that frontend guys have to make two calls, one for product details `GET /product/1` and second for it's customers `GET /product/1/customers`, there's no standard URI out there that offers the combination of the the output of these two services in one call, am I correct? and I've `GET /product/1` reserved for product details only (no customers)

Comment: No, that is not correct. I repeat, may be you did not read carefully. `GET /product/1` will output product and ALL associations made in model. `GET /product/1/customers` will output only customers for product with ID 1. So you can just `GET /product/1` to request product and all assciated data like customers

Comment: actually when you say "all associations made in model", that confuses me as I'm not much familiar with sails.js, please see my edit 2 based on what I've learned and correct me if there's something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: can you please look at the edit 2 to suggest me something good, I'm a bit short with timeline